Virtual python env for Custom operator in airflow DAG
Context:
I have complex custom operators in codebase. It is written  in Python, inherited from
BaseOperator. It's well structured implementation, & it does lot of pre & post processing (override pre_execute, execute & post_execute). Each of the operators within a DAG does its own complex functionality.
So far, it has been running fine on current Airflow environment.
Now, one of the operators in the DAG has a requirement for a new version of a Python library which conflicts with other operators in the same DAG.
Concept:
Create new Python virtual env & use it for applicable operator.
Reference:
I read about options like  PythonVirtualenvOperator & ExternalPythonOperator. But these are applicable for Python function only.
After looking at code, in PythonOperator related codeflow its implementation seems easy because it starts a subprocess for pythoncallback function  here.
But my requirement is for Custom implementation based on BaseOperator. Which can't use this option.
Question:
Do we opt to use a virtual environment for Custom Operator as well?
Any reference on how can this be achieved would be very helpful.

Your question needs to contain all the necessary information within the question itself (not in comments, behind external links, or in images or videos) and ideally nothing else.

My research into this topic ended in: this can't be achieved. Airflow runs inside it's own virtualenv and it uses that env everywhere. This is why every single operator that we use executes an external program - be it python - so that external program is not anyhow related or dependent on airflow environment. This allows to update airflow separately from everything else and keeps the dependencies contained. My only advice would be to either upgrade the whole airflow installtion, or ditch your current implementation and write it in such a way it executes external programs to the work.

how can this be achieved Overall, DAG processing is done by separate python processes that write the result to the database. Then, the scheduler reads from database and gives work to workers, all of them beeing separate processes. Scanning uses multiprocessing https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/dag_processing/manager.py#L154 , you would have to patch DagFileProcessorAgent to actually spawn different python processes to do the da procesing.
